# How to avoid base called method in xunit.net thanks to Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, parent-child, xunit.net

I'm trying to code unit test for my CutomSmtpMailer. My CutomSmtpMailer inherit from SmtpClient.

Here is how my class looks like :

```
public class CutomSmtpMailer : SmtpClient
{
    private void SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        //DoSomeStuff
        Send(mailMessage); //base.Send(mailMessage)
    }
}
```

I would like to test my custom code without sending mail : **I want to avoid the call of "Send(mailMessage)" by replacing it by an empty Action, not knowing if it has been called**. I knew how to mock an instance when i use DI, but i don't want to inject the SMTPclient (in fact i've numberous case with inheritence here is a simple exemple)

```
public class TestCutomSmtpMailer
{
    public CutomSmtpMailer Get()
    {
        return new CutomSmtpMailer();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SendMail()
    {
        CutomSmtpMailer service = Get();
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        // Find on web but not available :(
        Mock.Arrange(() => new SmtpClient().Send()).Returns(null).IgnoreInstance();
        service.SendMail(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

How to replace/Mock the Parent class method by an empty func to avoid sending mail ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't. This is why people would inject the `SmtpClient`.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Any particular reason you chose to go inherit from `SmtpClient`?

Comment: Also this was closed yesterday as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501213/how-to-mock-parent-class-to-unit-test-with-xunit-net) and you copied and pasted the entire content into a new question. That is not advised. Lets see if we can change this question enough to reveal the actual problem and avoid being a duplicate

Comment: Upvoted your question since it makes very clear what you want to do and what you want to avoid (dependency injection). This doesn't look like a duplicate to me, it's a very different situation to the one linked as duplicate with [the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501213/how-to-mock-parent-class-to-unit-test-with-xunit-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to inject the `SmtpClient` using *dependency injection*, you could go the ugly way and add an *internal* constructor and delegate to `CustomSmtpMailer` to aid in mocking and testing.
Please be aware that this approach is not very clean.
It will result in having code that is purely for testing in your product assembly which is usually not a good idea.

It does however solve your problem as described and gets you around having to use *dependency injection*.

```cs
public class CustomSmtpMailer : SmtpClient {

    internal delegate void SendInternal(MailMessage message);

    private SendInternal _sendAction;

    // make sure all your constructors call this one.
    // this will make the call to base.Send(MailMessage) the default behaviour.
    public CustomSmtpMailer() {
        _sendAction = delegate (MailMessage message) { Send(message); };
    }

    // customizes the SendMail(MailMessage) behaviour for testing purposes.
    internal CustomSmtpMailer(SendInternal sendAction) {
        _sendAction = sendAction;
    }

    private void SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage) {
        //DoSomeStuff

        _sendAction(mailMessage);
    }

}
```

Make the internal members visible to your test project by adding this to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` in your project.

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("My.Test.Assembly.Name")]
```

In your unit test you can use the internal constructor to configure the base call.

```cs
[Fact]
public void SendMail() {

    CustomSmtpMailer service = new CustomSmtpMailer(delegate (MailMessage message) {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a custom Action that can be used for testing");
    });
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    // Find on web but not available :(
    Mock.Arrange(() => new SmtpClient().Send()).Returns(null).IgnoreInstance();
    service.SendMail(mailMessage);

}
```